# How/where to keep google maps object in backbone to access it from multiple views

Tags: javascript, google-maps, backbone.js, google-geocoder

So I have a pretty easy app using Backbone.
I have collection of locations which I display.
I want to be able to click on one location and have the google location pin appear in the google map.

I actually have everything working but I hacked it to make it work.
I need the geocoder and the google map to be available from when I initialize it and also in the LocationSummaryView when it executes a search based on the address clicked. So to achieve this I passed the map and geocoder through all the view inits.

New to Backbone so just trying to work out best practices. I would like that all the google map code lives together.

AppView - I use require js which all works fine.

```
var AppView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '#locationapp',

    template: _.template(mainTemplate),
    map:null,
    geocoder:null,

    initialize: function() {

        this.collection = new LocationCollection();
        this.collection.bind("reset", _.bind(this.fetched, this));
        this.collection.fetch();

        this.setUpMap();

    },

    setUpMap: function() {
        var mapDiv = $("#map-canvas")[0];

        var mapOptions = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.7833, -122.4167),
            zoom: 14
        };
        this.map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, mapOptions);
        this.geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

        //hacky resizer I'll fix later
        var $win = $(window);
        var setMapSize = function() {
            if ($win.width() >= 500) {
                $(mapDiv).height($win.height());
            } else {
                $(mapDiv).height(300);
            }
        };
        $win.resize(setMapSize);
        setMapSize();
    },


    fetched: function() {
        this.locationList = new LocationListView({collection:this.collection, map:this.map, geocoder:this.geocoder});

    }
});
```

LocationListView

```
var LocationListView = Backbone.View.extend({
    //el is top level div
    el: '.location-search',
    filter: null,

    events: {
        "keyup #location-name-search" : "filterList"
    },

    initialize: function(options) {
        //You see what's going on here? just passing it on through
        this.map = options.map;
        this.geocoder = options.geocoder;
    },

    filterList: function(ev) {
        this.filter = $(ev.target).val();
        this.render();
    },

    render: function() {

        console.log("rendering list");
        var isMatchedLocation = true,
            view = null,
            title = '',
            locations = '';

        this.$(".location-list").empty();

        //kill the render after it has cleared if the filter is empty
        if (this.filter.length == 0) { return; }

        //AUTOCOMPLETE THING IS HERE
        //Just filtering which item views should be in the list
        var filter = this.filter.toLowerCase();
        var locationlist = this.collection.select(function(location) { 

            title = location.get("name").toLowerCase();
            //sift out empty locations
            locations = location.get("Locations") || false;
            isMatchedLocation = title.indexOf(filter) !== -1 && locations != false;

            if (isMatchedLocation === true) {
                view = new LocationSummaryView({
                    model: location,
                    map: this.map,
                    geocoder: this.geocoder
                });
                this.$(".location-list").append(view.render().el);
            }
            return isMatchedLocation;
        }, this);
    },
});
```

LocationSummaryView

```
var LocationSummaryView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'li',
    className: 'location-summary',
    map: null,
    geocoder: null,
    template: _.template(summaryTemplate),

    events: {
      'click': 'onSelected'
    },
    initialize: function(options) {
        //oh look at this familiar code
        this.map = options.map;
        this.geocoder = options.geocoder;
    },

    render: function() {
      this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.attributes));
      return this;
    },

    onSelected: function() {
        var location = this.model.get("Locations");
        this.setAddress(location);
    },

    setAddress: function(address) {
        var fullAddress = address + " San Francisco, CA";
        var self = this;
        this.geocoder.geocode( { 'address': fullAddress}, function(results, status) {
            // console.log(results);
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                console.log(this);

                self.map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: self.map,
                    position: results[0].geometry.location
                });
            } else {
                alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: The map view could listen for `'add'` events on a collection of locations and other things could add locations to that collection.

Comment: So make a MapView. Set up to listento a add event. 
My collection is static. Nothing is added or deleted. The changes happen when you click on one of the locations in a list. Then a google marker gets added to an array on the CollectionView

Comment: You can use a separate collection just for the markers if you want. You can also use a separate event bus to handle internal communication between components.